# Encontro da comunidade SOpt 3.0 Beta (13/12/2014 em São Paulo - SP, Brasil)

Tags: debate, meetup

## Update - Como foi!

Olá pessoal!

Não, não houve uma transmissão ao vivo, porque realmente rolou apenas um bate-papo entre os cinco presentes... Foi quase como diz o post do @Gabe - [Junte 3 pessoas numa sala](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2292/7998)... Só que sem a discórdia ;)

[image: Nós]

Da esquerda para direita: @BackFront, @Math, @EnzoTiezzi, @carlosrafaelgn e @LuizVieira. O @ValderíLeandro estava presente, mas não ficou na sala para sair na foto.

Foi uma manhã muito agradável, todos conseguiram se conhecer e conversamos **um bocado** sobre a comunidade e outros assuntos, das mais diversas áreas da vida :)

O resumo da conversa (que interessa para a comunidade): Sim, resolvemos fazer um encontro 4.0 em 2015, **com muito mais gente da comunidade**! O tópico principal sugerido: **realizar um "Meta Live"**, uma área de debate e discussões produtivas, sem a necessidade de ler milhares de comentários, ou ter que ficar "dando reload".

Vamos criar um novo post assim que tivermos mais notícias. Enquanto isso, vamos pensando em mais atividades para o ano que vem :D

Valeu!!!

---

Olá a todos da comunidade!

Estive conversando com o @Math por algum tempo, tentando ajustar os ponteiros para organizar o encontro da nossa comunidade.

Dessa vez coloquei "Beta" no título para ver se traz sorte ;)

A ideia é nos encontrarmos lá no espaço oferecido pela faculdade BandTec, a uns 200 metros da estação Paraíso de Metrô, como eu já havia proposto ao @Gabe nas últimas duas tentativas.

Dessa vez, a data sugerida por mim e pelo @Math é sábado, dia 13 de dezembro.

O horário ainda precisa ser definido por nós todos, desde que não comece antes das 8:00, e não termine depois das 17:00, por causa do horário de funcionamento da faculdade :)

Lembrando que a faculdade conta com notebooks, salas, pátio, auditório, Wi-Fi em todo o lugar, microfone sem fio, data show, Arduinos etc. **Se preciso, podemos transmitir o encontro ao vivo, utilizando a integração Hangouts+YouTube, ou outra ferramenta, caso desejado**.

Acredito que seria interessante irmos comentando aqui, para ter uma ideia de quem teria interesse em participar, ou simplesmente de opinar.

Depois, se for o caso, podemos criar algo mais formal com ferramentas como https://www.eventbrite.com ou Google Docs.

Na torcida!

---

## Update - Escopo

A receptividade foi ótima, isso indica que o encontro é algo que muitos desejam!

Assim, precisamos "bater o martelo" quanto a alguns assuntos.

### 1 - Modelo

O que será discutido / apresentado?

- Tecnologia em geral, como C, Java, JavaScript, NodeJS, AngularJS...
- Educação em geral
- A comunidade
- O site
- Uma mesa redonda sobre um ou mais tópicos
- Nossas experiências de vida
- Outros?!?

*Minha sugestão é dividir o encontro em slots de uma hora, com palestras/talks de 50 minutos sobre o SOpt (site, comunidade, fatos curiosos e futuro) ou sobre tecnologia (caso alguém deseje ministrar uma palestra).*

*Contudo, acredito ser interessante fazer o primeiro slot de maneira diferente, como uma "espécie de jogral", onde todos se apresentam, contam um pouco da vida, o que fazem, porque estão aqui, de onde vieram e para onde vão, de modo que consigamos nos conhecer melhor.*

### 2 - Horário

O horário foi definido como **09:00 - 13:00** encerrando com um almoço onde poderemos jogar conversa fora, nos conhecer melhor, "bater figurinhas" da copa, jogar Nintendo DS etc etc etc.

Existem alguns lugares ao redor da faculdade que poderiam "sediar" esse almoço, sem muito requinte ou frescura, mas com espaço e comida "limpinha".

As opções basicamente são (ver links):

- [Esfiha Chic](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Esfiha+Chic/@-23.578136,-46.6405436,18z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x94ce59905bce8029:0x735d60acd4c4bbcd!2sR.+Estela,+268+-+Vila+Mariana,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP,+04011-001,+Rep%C3%BAblica+Federativa+do+Brasil!3b1!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0xde5393b9a1f23ea6) (comida boa)
- [Flor do Paraíso](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Flor+do+Para%C3%ADso/@-23.5773727,-46.6410424,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x395224038b7daf14) (reza a lenda que eles têm uma feijoada ótima aos sábados)
- [Jaber](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jaber+Especialidades+%C3%81rabes/@-23.5780315,-46.6413107,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x84798b3289c09793) (comida boa, mas o espaço é pequeno, não comporta mais de 50 pessoas)
- [Babbo Giovanni](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Babbo+Giovanni/@-23.5779071,-46.6430678,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x5012c7cbb5f9335c) (comida boa, mas o espaço é muito pequeno, não comporta muito mais de 16 pessoas)
- [TemakiYa](https://www.google.com/maps/place/R.+Vergueiro,+1834+-+Vila+Mariana,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP,+Rep%C3%BAblica+Federativa+do+Brasil/@-23.5785938,-46.640299,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x94ce5985348bb995:0xbaa3a9de35436c33) (temaki, domburi, sashimi e rolls, muito boa a comida)

### 3 - Local e Estacionamentos

> Faculdade de Tecnologia Bandeirantes - Bandtec
> R. Estela, 268 - Vila Mariana
> São Paulo - SP
> 04011-001

Veja no [**Google Maps**](https://goo.gl/maps/oHTEt).

Preview:

[image: Preview do mapa do local]

---

Que acharam? :)

Comment: Um dos motivos de termos concordado que a data de 13/12 pode ser uma boa: Férias escolares! Tanto para os alunos como para os professores do site. E ainda não chegou a época dos festejos com a família, que acredito que poderia ser um complicador para a data de 20/12.

Comment: E se não forem férias dos professores, pelo menos eles estarão em um momento mais "relax" do semestre, como é o meu caso :)

Comment: Encontro internacional em Portugal :P

Comment: @Math e os trabalhadores que são a maioria? ;)

Comment: Qual formato vocês estão pensando para o encontro? Algo tipo uma mini-conferência? Workshop? Só um bate-papo?

Comment: @JorgeB. o problema dos trabalhadores resolvemos (pelo menos da maioria) marcando em um sábado. Daí maximizamos (ou pelo menos assim achamos) o tamanho do público considerando também os estudantes e professores :) Só não conseguimos considerar os portugueses nos nossos planos, rsrs.. Mas se quiser vir será bem vindo!

Comment: @bfavaretto boa pergunta! Na verdade apenas percebemos que tínhamos uma boa oportunidade de data e como já tínhamos o local resolvemos ver o que a comunidade achava de fazer um encontro. De fato faltou uma proposta de nossa parte sobre o tema, acho que fomos na empolgação das outras tentativas do Gabe tentar marcar o encontro e acabamos lançando uma proposta capenga :/ Agora que o tópico já foi criado mesmo acredito que poderíamos definir isso através daqui... Você tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Sugestão: 12h às 13h: almoço com bastante suco de laranja; 13h às 16h: mini-conferência e workshops; 16h às 17h: amigo secreto; 17h em diante: bate-papo num bar com cerveja e som não muito alto. Tenho um espremedor industrial de laranja, me comprometo a levá-lo caso queiram.

Comment: @Math Senti que me mencionaram aqui, sobre o suco ;)

Comment: O termo "suco de laranja" em qualquer lugar que for digitado no SOPT notifica o @utluiz imediatamente, hahaha..

Comment: @Math Ainda não posso confirmar presença, mas farei o possível para ir. Vou preparar uma apresentação *Stand Up* intitulada *10 motivos porque eu odeio Java*.

Comment: @utluiz essa eu não posso perder! rs

Comment: Eu vou nesse só pra ver o Stand Up do @utluiz.

Comment: @utluiz Excelente idéia. Mas você me deixou curioso - porque só 10?

Comment: @OnoSendai Porque ele adora o Java :D

Comment: "Tudo o que Você Sempre Quis Saber Sobre AngularJS (Mas Tinha Medo de Perguntar)"

Comment: @OnoSendai E também porque não quero entediar a platéia... :b

Comment: kkkkk- Gostaria de ir, mas MG fica um pouco longe. :(

Comment: Alguém pede ai uns bilhetes a SE para mandar para PT? :D

Comment: @bfavaretto agora sim uma apresentação formal (e séria) do escopo do encontro, na edição da pergunta, para caso ainda não tenha visto.

Comment: Vi agora, @Math! Eu voto manhã + almoço.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn pode colocar o meu nome nessa lista aí :D. Voto em manhã + almoço.

Comment: Só não vou por que a passagem de avião subiu muito

Comment: Faz o encontro 4 no RS :D vamos fazer um baita churrasco aqui!

Comment: Eu iria se fosse no **ES**. Apenas para não falar pouco: Eu acho que seria mais interessante se no lugar de organizar um encontro o SOpt apoiasse eventos sobre tecnologia, acho que seria muito mais iteressante e daria ainda mais visibilidade a comunidade.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck a ideia é legal, mas daí acho que ficaríamos dependentes dos funcionários do Stack Exchange, pois acredito que começa a envolver dinheiro, direito de imagem, patrocínio e coisas do gênero. Podemos usar o encontro também para fazermos um _brainstorm_ para ideias futuras, tipo a sua.

Comment: @Math demorou! Eu tenho muita vontade de ir, e honestamente até compraria uma passagem para SP só pra ir. Mas tenho medo de não rolar, sacou?

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck putz, Vila Velha é longinho mesmo. Entendo perfeitamente seu ponto, e por mais que o encontro estivesse confirmadíssimo ainda rola aquela pergunta "será que vale a pena tanto esforço para eu participar?" Talvez se você tivesse um familiar por aqui já emendava uma visita e outras coisas mais, para fazer valer a viagem. De qualquer forma, só de conversarmos aqui tive uma outra ideia (que não faço a menor ideia de como implementar): Live Stream!! :D Já pensou? ia reunir muito mais pessoas. Ajuda a desenvolver essa ideia ai! Como poderíamos fazer isso?

Comment: @anmaia OK! Anotado! :)

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck e Math temos banda e equipamento para fazer a transmissão em tempo real! Vou editar a pergunta, para colocar mais essa informação!

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn tem **tudo pronto** para uma **transmissão ao vivo**? Sério mesmo? :O estou chocado.. esse evento vai ser um baita de um sucesso se continuar assim, hehehe

Comment: @Math Sério! Direto a gente transmite usando o hangouts direto pra dentro do youtube. Mas pode utilizar outras ferramentas! :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn dá para a platéia participar? Tipo telões mostrando a cara do povo por WebCam e áudio?

Comment: @Math se fizer pelo Hangout+YouTube, nós conseguimos mostrar aqui, em nosso projetor, o vídeo+áudio do "lado de lá", desde que eles tenham câmeras e microfones ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn se rolar na web eu apareço com certeza!

Comment: OK! Me comprometo a criar um live broadcast, *se o evento rolar*! hehehehe ;)

Comment: +1  _"se rolar na web eu apareço com certeza!"_

Comment: @JorgeB. estamos esperando sua confirmação. Só quer saber de ganhar passagem de avião, rs.. E agora? Confirma presença pela Web?

Comment: Confirmadissima :)

Comment: +1+ pro Hangout no dia do encontro, a assistência vai quintuplicar :) . . . . E fica a sugestão de **Cabo Verde** quando fizermos o Encontro Internacional que o @Jorge propôs; fica a meio caminho de Salvador da Bahia e Lisboa!

Comment: ahahahahah @brasofilo mais vale São Tomé :D

Comment: Alguém paga minha passagem para eu ir? Eu seria o único Acreano no evento! kkkkkk

Comment: Vale lembrar que dia 11/12/2014 é aniversário de um ano do SOPT =)

Comment: @Math Mais um excelente motivo!!!! Como minha vó diz: "Não pode comemorar antes, dá azar! Mas depois... Sem problemas!" :)

Comment: Isso aí é em SP?

Comment: @JoãoNeto, você se incomoda com piadas sobre o Acre?

Comment: Me incomodo não Bruno, aqui nem existe, eu mesmo sou uma invenção da globo. Kkkkkkkk

Comment: Então, justamente por isso. Eu ia dizer que talvez você seria o único acreano do planeta no evento.

Comment: Kkkkkkkk, se eu tivesse esbanjando dinheiro eu ia oh, mas ia ficar perdido no meio de voces, meu nivel de conhecimento não é tão alto :(

Comment: Disseram que a tal faculdade é a 200m do metrô. Ainda assim é capaz de eu me perder.

Comment: Olá pessoal. Ainda estou aguardando o resultado de um evento que possivelmente ocorrerá no mesmo final de semana, mas a manhã de sábado dia 13 de dezembro parece uma ótima data. Vou me esforçar pra participar! Vai ser muito massa esse encontro! :)

Comment: vai rolar mesmo então??

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Ao que tudo indica, sim. O prédio está reservado, a data também, a palestra do utluiz parece de pé, e a mesa redonda, também. Será que ajuda criar um formulário, algo como Google Forms?

Comment: atualizou o título no boletim :D achei que mostrar data e local no boletim poderia atrair mais pessoas que passarem o olho no título

Comment: @Math Boa ideia!!! :D

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn acho que seria uma boa nos prepararmos para bater o martelo quanto ao horário e atualizar as informações no post, para que alguém que está chegando aqui pela primeira vez por exemplo não fique perdido em um oceano de comentários e _edits_. Aparentemente o horário da manhã venceu, só o bigown que deixou claro que preferia outro horário mas pelo jeito ele foi minoria. Eu na vdd nem opinei quanto ao horário, o que for pra mim tá bom. Se ninguém mais se manifestar vai acabar por ser esse horário mesmo. PS: fiz mais uma edição

Comment: @Math criei um "formulariozinho"! Será que o pessoal vai preencher?!?!? :)

Comment: Seria interessante uma transmissão ao vivo, ainda mais se for utilizado o Hangouts, ele irá armazenar no Youtube para ver depois.

Comment: Oi @FelipeStoker! Sim! Se o pessoal comparecer, faremos a transmissão ao vivo via Hangouts/YouTube! :D

Comment: Tem estacionamento no local? Se não, tem algum que você recomenda?

Comment: Caros organizadores (carlosrafaelgn e @Math): vou precisar desconfirmar minha presença :( Vou precisar levar minha filha numa festinha no sábado de manhã, não vai ter jeito. Uma pena. Mas se vocês usarem mesmo o hangout, prometo assistir tudo depois :) Fica o utluiz como único representante da equipe de moderação então.

Comment: Ok @bfavaretto! Depois eu publico o link ;)

Comment: Tá rolando live??

Comment: Ainda não. Assim que começar eu posto o link aqui.

Comment: Eu queria ter ido, mas tava chovendo muito aqui no dia.

Answer (score 16):

Bem, gostaria de confirmar minha presença no tão esperado encontro da comunidade.

## Horário

Em concordância com o @bfavaretto, **voto para que o encontro seja na parte da manhã**.

Na verdade, acho que todo o dia não seria suficiente para alguns, mas creio que esta é a melhor solução para maximizar o número de participantes. Um encontro que durasse o dia inteiro seria mais desgastante e inviável para quem tem algum outro compromisso. Meio período é mais fácil de encaixar na agenda e, para os preguiçosos, um motivo a menos para preguiça. ;)

## Conteúdo

Pelo tempo disponível, palestras longas seriam inadequadas. Até porque todos devem estar mais é querendo se conhecer e bater papo sobre várias coisas.

Minha sugestão para o programa é algo assim:

```
EncontroSOpt({

  [ 09.00 -> 10.00 ] => Apresentação_dos_Participantes(usuário, nome, trabalho, tecnologias, *),
  [ 10.00 -> 11.30 ] => Lightning_Talks('palestras curtas de 10 minutos, técnicas ou não'),
  [ 11.30 -> 12.30 ] => Mesa_Redonda('SOpt', 'qualquer assunto')

}).done( Almoço )
```

## Almoço

Voto na **Esfiha Chic** ou **Flor do Paraíso**, mas topo outras sugestões. Só não sou chegado a peixe cru.

## O que você pode esperar de mim

Além de participar do que vocês decidirem e ajudar no que puder, se me permitirem gostaria de fazer uma mini apresentação intitulada:

> ## 5 razões porque Java é a melhor linguagem do Universo<sup>1</sup>
>
> Onde eu vou mostrar as maravilhas ocultas desta plataforma que só os "Javeiros" mais bravos do mundo já conheceram.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> Sim, é uma ironia.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Sim, é outra ironia.</sup>

---

### Atualização sobre a duração e o conteúdo

Entendo que para quem vem de longe, um programa de meio período não é tão atrativo. Viajar longas horas para voltar depois apenas três ou quatro não faz muito sentido.

Particularmente, eu não posso ficar o dia todo. Mas sugiro que os que tiverem mais disponibilidade de combinar mais atividades durante a tarde, seja na BandTec ou em outro lugar.

Comment: Totalmente a favor de tudo isso!

Comment: Nossa, +100 pro programa! Kibe cru é show :)

Comment: Podemos fazer algo no estilo do [Why Linux Sucks? / Why Linux Doesn't Suck?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pOxlazS3zs) para Java :D.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly tipo em um tribunal que tem um advogado de acusação e um de defesa? Daí o [Duke](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Duke_Wave.png) seria o réu. O utluiz é o de defesa e o Cigano é o de acusação. O bfavaretto pode ser o juiz, eu e você somos testemunhas de defesa e o Carlos faz parte do corpo de jurados. Era algo assim que tinha pensando? PS: O vídeo é muito longo, não dá para eu ver agora.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Ainda não pude assistir ao vídeo, mas na verdade minha ideia é fazer graça com alguns pontos do Java.

Comment: Dá para fazer um debate com mais qualidade do que o da Globo. O ponto do vídeo é que com os mesmos slides você pode interpretar que uma coisa presta e não presta. Java é bem assim. Temos Genéricos! Mas eles são implementados com *type erasure*... Temos Lambdas! Quer dizer, quase... Temos arrays covariantes! E por isso mesmo eles estão quebrados... Temos o operador diamante! Mas isso é o máximo que o Java faz para inferir tipos... A JVM é mega hiper rápida e suporta n linguagens! Mas até hoje ninguém se deu ao trabalho de implementar *tail call optimization* no compilador do Java.

Comment: Saímos de uma palestra que não teria fim para uma que vai acabar em 30 segundos :)

Comment: Eu quero saber que mais poderíamos fazer? Para quem é de fora, precisa maximizar o esforço da viagem. Estou quase dentro mas ainda tem chão para eu ter certeza.

Comment: @bigown Independentemente do que for acontecer das 10:00 às 11:30, a ideia das 09:00-10:00 e das 11:30 às 12:30 acho que já está bem legal para um primeiro encontro :)

Comment: @bigown aproveita a indecisão do povo para dar a sua sugestão de atividades, existem grandes chances dela ser aceita :)

Comment: 9 da manhã eu ainda tô babando nos travesseiros (sim, no plural) :P Fora que é incrível a capacidade que eu tenho de pegar metrô lotado, não importa o horário eu sempre vou de pé. >:( Isso se eu não me perder no caminho >.<

Comment: @Math não tem nada específico que estou pensando, só queria maximizar o tempo mesmo, não gastar dinheiro e principalmente mais horas me deslocando que no encontro mesmo.

Comment: @bigown aproveita para fazer as compras de natal para a família, na parte da tarde na 25 de março :)

Comment: @Math O que o bigown fez contra você para mandá-lo para a 25 no meio de dezembro? ;)

Comment: @bigown se você ainda tiver interesse em vir e propor um outro horário poderia postar outra resposta com sua própria proposta. Como só temos a resposta do utluiz acho que é o que a maioria prefere, mas se surgir uma proposta concorrente e receber muitos votos podemos mudar os planos. Caso contrário em alguns poucos dias atualizamos a _pergunta_ com as informações oficiais.

Comment: e se o evento durasse até a tarde? @bfavaretto

Comment: @PauloRoberto Mesmo assim não poderia confirmar com certeza. Fim de ano tá um rolo.

Answer (score 6):

Está tudo ótimo, concordo com todos os quesitos **exceto uma coisa**:

> Porque apenas no horário da manhã?

Afinal, as *palestras e etc* poderiam acontecer demanhã mesmo, porém o encontro poderia durar até a tarde, pois **[quem vai vir de longe pra caramba](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3082/paulo-roberto)**  gostaria de aproveitar o máximo possível o encontro, porque né, **não acham triste se deslocar de Criciúma - SC para SP capital e aparecer no encontro e ficar algumas horinhas e ir embora?**

Tudo bem que devo ser praticamente (ou realmente) o único a vir de longe mas, acredito que não seja a minha pessoa a única a querer um encontro com maior duração, até porque quem tiver compromissos ou algo do tipo está livre para ir, não é? e quem estiver livre para ficar, estaria aproveitando o encontro,

> Desta forma, todos nós ficaríamos felizes <strike>*inclusive eu*</strike>

Quanto ao lugar para comer, sugiro que haja uma maneira democrática de decidir, no momento do almoço, realizamos uma rápida *votação* para decidir qual o lugar que iremos comer, **que tal?**

#### Porém temos que nos certificar que não haja ninguém alérgico a "tal" tipo de comida que decidimos, ou que odeie <strike>mais que odeia Java</strike> a comida escolhida.

## Outra coisa:

Temos que ter consciência que nem todo mundo terá acesso a internet no momento que chegou em frente a faculdade, por isso este alguém pode não fazer a mínima idéia <strike>no caso eu denovo</strike> de onde exatamente irá acontecer o encontro, por isso uma orientação com flechas ou indicando certinho onde seria, ou alguém esperando, logo na entrada, seria de bom grado.

> <strike>Ou agente poderia jogar Poker valendo reputação</strike>, just kidding.

Comment: Vou levar você pra ir comer um bife no pão no Flor do Paraíso, garoto. É bem perto dali.

Comment: Cadê vcs dois? Paulo e @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @Math Acabei de acordar. Esse horário ficou osso pra mim.