# Estado da Pilha #2: Junte 3 pessoas numa sala

Tags: debate

> "Adoro o cheiro de comunidades pela manhã. Tem cheiro de discórdia!"
> <sup>*Tenente-coronel Bill Kilgore*</sup>

Se você não se lembra dessa parte de [Apocalypse Now](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_Now), é porque ela não existe. Mas se, ao invés da Guerra do Vietname<sup>1</sup>, o filme usasse como tema um fórum na internet eu tenho certeza de que essa cena iria ocorrer. Além disso, o título do filme provavelmente continuaria o mesmo.

Diz a lenda que se você juntar 3 pessoas em uma sala, elas não nunca mais entrarão em acordo. Eu não sei onde ouvi isso, e não sei se é verdade, mas se não for verdade para 3 pessoas certamente é para 11400. Eu diria que todos vocês concordam comigo, mas isso iria de encontro ao meu próprio argumento... Então, um abraço para você que discorda!

A civilização existe há uns 7 mil anos, pelo menos, e desde então nós estamos tentando fazer todo mundo se entender, e falhando. Cada pessoa é um aglomerado de experiências, de intenções conscientes (e subconscientes), e de expectativas que fundamentam seu próprio ponto de vista. A única coisa em comum entre todos é que cada um de nós tem a forte crença de que estamos corretos.

Não significa que somos irredutíveis, mas sim que sempre que expressamos uma opinião ela representa uma convicção, e requeremos de outros o esforço de contrapor o que dizemos se quiserem mudar nossa opinião.

Até hoje, em sistemas de governo, conferências da ONU, reunião de pais na escola ou no SOpt, ninguém chegou a uma maneira de satisfazer todas as perspetivas sobre um assunto. Essa é a natureza do debate aberto... Alguém sempre vai discordar, sem obter as evidências que acredita serem necessárias para mudar sua própria opinião. E ressentir o resto por ter "ignorado o óbvio".

Ouvir *todas* as disposições, à favor ou contra, sobre *todos* os casos e tentar chegar a uma solução que satisfaça todas elas é irreal. A melhor maneira que temos para lidar com esse problema é usar as regras estabelecidas pela própria comunidade/grupo/dojo/nação. As regras **definitivamente** não agradam a todos, e sofrem da mesma falta de concordância, mas são a melhor maneira de se chegar a uma decisão em tempo hábil. É a maneira que temos de avançar a discussão e seguir em frente, mesmo que ignorando a discordância de uma parte.

## A regra é clara<sup>2</sup>

Nenhuma regra é clara. Se fossem, não existiriam advogados ou comentaristas de arbitragem. Idealmente - como acredito ser o caso no nosso site - elas são criadas a partir do melhor das nossas habilidades, experiências, observações. Tentamos criá-las de forma não tendenciosa e abrangente. Queremos que elas sejam amplas o suficiente para não precisarem ser aplicadas a todos os posts, mas claras o suficiente para nos ajudarem a resolver os casos em que elas precisam ser aplicadas.

Nossas regras são filhas da filosofia do Stack Exchange com a experiência da comunidade. Algumas nascem de um lado, outras nascem de outro. São resultado de debate extenso, privado ou público, e visam sempre o **melhor para o site**.

Com a exceção de spammers e trolls, **todos** os 11 mil membros da comunidade querem o melhor para o site. Nós todos podemos não estar em acordo sobre *o quê* representa o melhor para o site, e como chegar lá, mas é inegável que cada um de nós quer que nossa comunidade cresça, seja forte e continue ajudando o máximo possível de pessoas por anos a fio.

**Entender que seu "adversário" quer o mesmo que você não é fácil, mas é essencial para que todos se entendam**. As regras, e as interpretações delas elas, não vão agradar a todos o tempo todo. O que é bom, porque nenhum de nós está certo o tempo todo.

Seu ponto de vista ser aceito pela maioria não significa que seja o correto. Assim como ninguém concordar com você não significa que esteja errado. Não é uma questão de vencer ou perder, mas de manter a harmonia do site e trabalhar para o melhor. Todos queremos o mesmo, ainda que tenhamos ideias diferentes de como chegar lá.

## É o fim, é o caos

O quão frágil é uma comunidade? Acho que ela é tão frágil quanto o apreço que seus membros têm por ela. Uma comunidade em que todos concordam, mas não se importam, provavelmente viverá à perigo. Em contra partida, uma comunidade que vivem em debate alimentado pelo empenho e apego dos seus membros, tem muito mais chances de continuar forte. Desde que as divergências de opinião se mantenham civilizadas, claro.

O SOpt tem uma das comunidades mais engajadas da rede. Muitos aqui lutam, com unhas e dentes, pelo que acreditam. Se fazem ouvir. Se fazem notar. Debatem, discordam e concordam. Nós não vamos definhar tão cedo. Eu confio em todos vocês e acredito que isso vale para a gigantesca maioria.

Vocês estão construindo algo novo e importante. Não é uma tarefa fácil, para ninguém. Ocorrerão percalços e tropeços, decisões erradas e decisões corretas, caos e ordem. Alguns irão, outros virão. Mas enquanto vocês se importarem como, **não há o que temer**.

O [primeiro post no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/12) diz:

> Via de regra, por enquanto é melhor permitir qualquer pergunta que satisfaça as seguintes condições:
>
> - Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?
> - Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?

Estes são os fundamentos básicos do SOpt. Queremos ajudar o máximo possível de pessoas; Queremos tornar a internet um lugar melhor. Acredito que estamos sendo bem sucedidos em ambos, então não há o que temer. Uma pergunta não vai selar o futuro do site. Nenhum de nós vai permitir que o caos absoluto seja instaurado.

O futuro do SOpt não deve ser *protegido* a ferro e a fogo. Ele deve ser *cultivado* com boas ideias e colaboração. Ser precavido, manter sempre um olhar crítico e atento sobre o estado atual das coisas é muito bom. A experiência de muitos aqui conta muito ao avaliar os casos. Mas ela também cria um viés no nosso julgamento, ao qual precisamos sempre estar atentos.

## Não tenha medo de ajudar

O Shog escreveu um [post no MSF](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6713/186169) que acho que pode nos ajudar:

> Caution avoids a question because the problem is unclear; fear screams at the asker because he might be a vampire. Caution leads us to make changes carefully while examining the consequences; fear leads to paralysis and politician's logic.
> [...]
> I would *love* to see everyone here rise to the challenge. But if you are to do so, you must first overcome your fear:
>
> 1. **Don't fear negative reactions from those whose work is criticized.** Be honest and civil in your critique, focusing on the problems you hope to see corrected rather than the author who created them. If it happens that you've cast your pearls before swine, then call upon the moderators to stop them from trampling you.
> 2. **Don't fear that your edit will inadvertently deviate from the author's intent.** If you edit in good faith, according to your best interpretation of the author's intentions, then it will be easy for them to correct inaccuracies should you err. [A substantive edit][2] that salvages a poorly-written post can prove invaluable for both the author *and* those who come after; a timid edit just wastes your time.
> 3. **Don't fear that you may inadvertently help someone who ended up in the wrong place.** If you write your answer to be useful to your peers, then it may well be of service to such *even if the asker is not among them!*
>
> ---
>
> Ter cautela é evitar alimentar uma pergunta porque o problema não está bem definido; ter medo é gritar contra o autor porque ele pode ser um vampiro. Cautela nos ajuda a mudar as coisas com cuidado e avaliar as consequências; medo leva à paralisia completa e à [lógica do político](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism)<sup>3</sup>
> [...]
> Eu *adoraria* ver todos aqui aceitarem o desafio [de serem mais gentis]. Mas se forem fazer isso, primeiro vocês precisam superar seus medos:
>
> 1. **Não tenha medo da reação de quem você critica.** Seja honesto e educado ao criticar os outros, mantenha o foco nos problemas que você está vendo, e não em quem os criou. Se suas críticas não forem recebidas com a mesma cordialidade que você as enviou, avise a moderação.
> 2. **Não tenha medo de que sua edição pode alterar o sentido da pergunta.** Se você acredita que sua edição é válida, de acordo com a sua interpretação da intenção do autor, não será difícil corrigir qualquer erro eventual. Uma [edição substancial](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) que salva uma pergunta mal escrita é importante tanto para o autor quanto para todo que acessarem a pergunta depois; uma edição tímida, por outro lado, provavelmente é um desperdício do seu tempo.
> 3. **Não tenha medo de ajudar alguém que não entendeu muito bem o site.** Se você escrever uma resposta útil para as pessoas no site, então ela é uma boa resposta, *mesmo que não sirva para o autor!*

É essa mentalidade que constrói uma comunidade forte. Não tenha medo de ajudar uma pergunta ruim, mesmo que sua primeira reação seja de completa rejeição. Estamos todos aprendendo e evoluindo. Nossa comunidade vai crescer e passar por diversas transformações, não há motivo para tentar prever *como* ela vai ser no futuro.

Na dúvida, lembre sempre do nosso primeiro e único lema:

### Divirta-se!

---

<sup>1.</sup> Essa foi pra galera de Portugal
<sup>2.</sup> Essa foi pra galera do Brasil
<sup>3.</sup> Essa é a falácia lógica do tipo:

1. Algo preciso ser feito
2. Isto é algo
3. Então isto precisa ser feito

Comment: Excelente texto Gabe, só não percebi o ponto 1... Editei ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Valeu! Aparentemente eu não sei mais escrever....

Comment: Acontece a todos Gabe :)

Comment: Até escorreu uma 'gota de suor dos olhos' depois que li esse texto.

Comment: Números não parece ser o ponto forte do Gabe :p

Comment: No aguarde de mais dois - [Mercado de Trabalho](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19602/pilha-estourada-mercado-de-trabalho)

Answer (score 10):

Como diz um pensamento que carrego comigo:

> Pare de tentar não ser tolo e comece a tentar ser inteligente.

A ideia principal é ser assertivo, direcionar seus esforços para aquilo que você busca alcançar sem medo de fracassar ou de demonstrar deficiências...

E se você está errando pouco, significa que está tentando pouco, é comum para qualquer mortal errar milhares de vezes na jornada de crescimento, isto é, todos nós estamos sujeitos a cometer erros/equívocos. Como você Gabe bem disse, o negócio é aproveitar o percurso de forma divertida e lembrar que todos aqui devem atuar tendo em mente sinergia.

<strike>(Trechos do meu futuro livro em parceria com Paulo Coelho)</strike>

Answer (score 10):

> Divertires-te até à p*ta da loucura: eis a tua maior prova de sanidade.

Com a experiência que vou adquirindo ao logo dos anos, a cada dia que passa, mais tenho a certeza que nada sei.

Quando começo a ter mais conhecimentos sobre um determinado assunto, nessa altura reparo que afinal não sei *nada* sobre esse assunto.

No SOpt estou a 8 meses e ninguém imagina o que já aprendi por aqui. Não só em termos de programação que tenho aprendido muito, mas **principalmente** em termos de relações humanas. É ótimo sentir que temos amigos aqui apesar de nunca nos termos visto na vida. Acho que se tivesse agora de viver sem este site ficaria triste.

Mas voltado ao assunto, errar é humano e é a errar que se aprende. É uma das premissas da minha curta vida:

> Nunca me arrependo de *nada* que tenha feito

mesmo os erros que cometi, porque foram esses mesmos erros que me fizeram crescer e ser o homem que sou hoje, e que adoro.

Claro que para tudo há um limite que se deve ter sempre em mente:

**RESPEITO PARA COM OS OUTROS**

Isso sim é o mais importante, respeitar e ser respeitado. Se todo o mundo se respeitasse viveríamos num mundo bem melhor.